# Is there a Translation of the Quran in English that contains meanings and historical context that is relatively concise and objective?

Tags: quran, tafseer, quran-translation, books

To give some background, I have the Quran in the original Arabic (alas, while I can read the letters, I hardly understand the language), as well as a copy that is a 3-volume word-for-word English translation. While reading these, I have found that there are verses that I cannot fully comprehend.

I am seeking an English translation that provides fairly objective meanings of the verses (without delving into personal interpretation), along with the historical context of the revelations. Ideally, it would not be many volumes long. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I prefer physical books to online sources, so knowing where the book/s can be ordered would also be helpful.

Comment: You are looking for a tafsir. There are various options, e.g. an abridged version of Tafsir Ibn Kathir and the Tafsir of Maududi are available in english. You can find them online or search to get physical copies.

Answer (score 2):

Well , you could try tafsir of other scholars on YouTube like :
Noumal Ali Khan (Bayiinah Institute)
Dr.Yasir Qadhi
Advocate Faiz Syed (Urdu Speaker)
In books I would recommend The Noble Qur'an of Dr Muhsin Khan

Comment: this didn't age well